# Display reformatted date from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php

I have a field within a MySQL database that has a date format of the following:

```
Mon, 17 Aug 2015 19:14:22 +0100
```

I want to display this date using PHP in the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

I have no idea how to pick out the different elements and reformat them.

Can somebody help?

Many thanks,

John

Comment: `$date = new \Datetime($mydate); echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try these :-

```
$date    = "Mon, 17 Aug 2015 19:14:22 +0100";
$newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));

echo $newDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in mysql

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(test.dateFrom, '%Y-%M-%d %H:%i:%s') as date,
FROM test
```

Or in php

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($datefrommysql) );
```